# SPO: Workflow not working

Tags: designer-workflow, column, people-picker

I have this basic workflow that would get the value of the "created by" column and would populate it as a user name in a people column. The issue is it is not working. I can see the flow going to stage 1 but the people column would not populate itself. Workflow image below.

[image]

Comment: I think the IF condition is wrong. Try adding a log to history inside `IF` loop (before `Set PWID to ..` action) and see if the execution goes into the loop. Also what is PWID? workflow variable?

Comment: Hi. PWID is a Person Column that is set to show field as email. So instead of users typing in their email the workflow should get the value if "Created by" and copy it over to the PWID field and it would show as email.

Comment: You need to use the `update item` action to update the column in sharepoint list. is workflow execution goes into IF loop? try adding log to history as I suggested in above comment.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the detailed steps to achieve your requirements.

1. For If condition you need to check the created by of current Item.

[image]

2. Use Update List Item action to set the value of PWID column.

[image]

3. Set PWID will look like the below image.

[image]

4. The complete workflow will look something like below.

[image]

Let me know if still, it is not working after updating the workflow based on the steps mentioned above.